# Need to assign an auto increment value to the varchar column of table and table without using in I'd column as auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had a table of `Transaction`, in that table I don't have any ID column. I have to generate a unique value in the form of `"0901201900001"`.

Above format is the combination of today's date and the value 00001.

00001 - it's autoincremented value for the same day only. Next day it should start with 00001 again.

Output should be like this

```
0901201900001
0901201900002
0901201900003
.
.
.
09012019000050
1001201900001
.
.
.
10012019000050
```

Comment: you can use string manipulation to figure out what the next available value is, but you may also have to check for collisions or otherwise avoid them, that can be done different ways, record locks, triggers, constraints, error handling, mutexes.

Comment: I need to create the physical table which generates mentioned format and when I am inserting rows in that table that formatted value should be inserted

Comment: I would advise you not to do this like you are trying to do. You are violating 1NF by putting two pieces of data into a single column. I would instead use two columns for this data and then a computed column to hold the two pieces of data. You could create a sequence and alter it with a sql job to cycle it every day.

Comment: Can u provide same example of what u r saying

Comment: @SeanLange https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186426/stuffstringconcat

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @Sean Lange says, this is gross. Combining a date and a generated number is taking two pieces of data (date and a surrogate key) and making them one column. You are always going to be parsing out what the data is and trying to figure out what the date is. Instead you want to make your key a date and the sequence id.

That being said, here is something that you can do to address your original problem.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.SQ_RestartableSequence  AS INT INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CYCLE
-- Run this every day right before midnight. Gross, but it's the only way to get what you want
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.SQ_RestartableSequence RESTART WITH 1

CREATE TABLE SequenceTest 
( ID VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE), 1), '/', '') + RIGHT( '0000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_RestartableSequence AS VARCHAR(30)), 4)
, ValueField Varchar(30)
)


INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceTest
(ValueField)
VALUES
(   'Test Value')

INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceTest
(ValueField)
VALUES
(   'Test Value2')


SELECT *
FROM dbo.SequenceTest AS st
```

Comment: I messed up the date format, but you can take the principal and figure out the format you need.